# Using combo box in c#

Tags: c#

I have prepared a program about grocery management. In one place I have to put product category and product brand. Product brands are in one combo box and categories are in another combo box. I want to change the brand combo box according to the text display in category combo box. Eg: if you choose chocolates in category combo box, the brand combo box shows "Mars"," Snickers" and so on. Please help me. I want the c# code for this work. Thank you. I am Sandu.

Comment: Wow, not only do we have no idea of your stack (ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms, etc.) but you are simply asking for someone to write a bunch of code for you without your having shown any effort whatsoever.

Comment: I did some steps. But there's no use of it. That's why I asked someone to help me

Comment: Please, provide your (relevant) code

Comment: I didn't start to write the code. I added items to both combo boxes & named first combo box as "category" & other one is "brand".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i ll try to give you a quick example in Windows Forms.

Like you said, you got 2 combo boxes Category and Brand, i named cmbParent and cmbChild.

I declared some variables:

```
List<String> listParent = new List<String>();
List<Tuple<String, String>> listChild = new List<Tuple<String,String>>();
```

On Form_Load, i did some manual lists:

```
public ComboForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listParent.Add("Sports");
        listParent.Add("Countries");
        listParent.Add("Continents");

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Sports", "Handball"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Sports", "Golf"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Sports", "Skimboarding"));

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Countries", "Portugal"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Countries", "Mozambique"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Countries", "Mexico"));

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Continents", "Asia"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("Continents", "Oceania"));

        foreach (var item in listParent)
        {
            cmbParent.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

And added an event on the cmbParent, when you change the selected item, it will change the cmbChild.

```
private void cmbParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String i = cmbParent.Text;
        cmbChild.Items.Clear(); //clear the child combo items.
        foreach (var item in listChild)
        {
            if (item.Item1.Equals(i))
            {
                cmbChild.Items.Add(item.Item2);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps, and give you an hint.

Comment: Can't you show me the full code? I didn't get some points in this code

Comment: @user228285 what didnt you get ? this is the full code, i only avoided the "public partial class MainForm : Form"

Comment: Ok. Do I declare variables first before the first coding part in this window?

Comment: @user228285 Yes, you do :)

Comment: Thank you. I will be back after adding this code to my project.

Comment: In the last part of the code 'listChild' is underlined by a red line. This shows that it is a mistake

Comment: @user228285 listChild, is your variable , that you declared in the begin. maybe you got another name. I edited, to be easier for you to follow the sequence.

Comment: My code is not working. I can't understand the my mistake. Sholud I send my code to you

Comment: @user228285 first, what is the error ? what is the message that you get when you mouse over the error ?

Comment: "The name 'listChild' does not exist in the current context." This is the thing

Comment: @user228285 check the name above, where you declared the variable. They are not the same. Remember the 1st line of code , is before the form_load method.

Comment: Ok. I add like this. This time there's no any errors highlighted. But the program does not work. A message box tells that there are errors

Comment: @user228285 Post the errors, please..

Comment: I copied all the codes to another form. Now the program is working. Thank you so much

Comment: @user228285 Awsome :) glad to help. if you can mark as answered

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2015? How to add databases here? I can't use the same way in 2010 version?

Comment: @user228285 that is another question. Mark this as answered, if it helped you. And ask a new question, and we will try to help you :)